# How to try this Scala code?

Tags: scala, date, eclipse-juno

If I want to try this code to practice how Scala handles time and dates, should I create a new Scala application or just a new Scala class in Eclipse:

```
sealed abstract class SmartTime extends Ordered[SmartTime] { x =>
        def compare(y: SmartTime) = {
                x match {
                        case InfiniteFuture => 1
                        case InfinitePast => -1
                        case ConcreteTime(x) =>
                                y match {
                                        case InfiniteFuture => -1
                                        case InfinitePast => 1
                                        case ConcreteTime(y) => x compare y
                                }
                }
        }
}
case class ConcreteTime(t: Long) extends SmartTime
case object InfiniteFuture extends SmartTime
case object InfinitePast extends SmartTime

object Main {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
                val y = ConcreteTime(100)
                val z = ConcreteTime(10)
                val x = InfiniteFuture
                val p = InfinitePast
                println(Vector(y, z, x, p).sortWith(_ < _))
        }
}
```

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164843

I tried the date, calendar and time handling of python, java, and C++ and I thought neither was very good. Python was the best since it's relatively easy to state what you want with a timestamp and a timedelta but I think Java has made it confusing forcing us to use a Calendar object which we don't have to use in python. Now I want to try handling timestamps and time in Scala to learn Scala. The code above was posted and I would like to try it. Can you help me?

[image]

I can run the code and change it in Eclipse, now I want to try write I test case or try that no matter which date into the future you are, the infinite future is still ahead of that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want really is the fastest way to know what the output of this program is without any hassle, then you can use http://www.simplyscala.com/, which is an online scala interpreter (scala 2.8).
Just paste your code in the edit box and click "evaluate". Then enter `Main.main(Array.empty)` and click "evaluate" again. The main program will evaluate and you'll get your result.

Then, if you really plan to learn scala, there are enough tutorials around the web regarding the use of Eclipse/IntelliJ/SBT with scala. A good book might help too.

Comment: Doh! It turns out that you were already given the solution. The person that posted the code at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164843 also provided a link to "ideone" (which will also let you compile scala code): http://ideone.com/K5Kuk

Comment: One could prefer http://www.scalakata.com/ over simplyscala because it is simply much more beautiful (but unlike simply scala, it shows not every value, so you have to explicitly print them) and has shareable snippets: http://www.scalakata.com/5139b09fe4b0d323913d1763.

Answer (score 4):

A local counterpart to Simply Scala is to run the Scala REPL:

```
% scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

I always have a terminal tab with a stock Scala REPL running. (I've even written a script that restarts it automatically in case I fumble-finger a CTRL-D or trip over a bug that ends the REPL or the JVM.)

If you have a project with dependencies and you are using SBT (you *are* using SBT, right?), you can launch a REPL whose classpath includes your code and your dependencies, which is more than a little convenient!

```
% sbt
> console
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/rschulz/Projects/scribble/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can also use a [Scala worksheet](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started).

While Java date/time handling is generally considered to be abysmal, there is a very widely used alternative: [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), and a [Scala wrapper](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time) for it.